# Remove the unnecessary Boolean literal(s) issue in SonarQube - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, sonarqube

SonarQube is throwing an error for the following 2 ternary expressions in my C#(v10) controller class citing `Remove the unnecessary Boolean literal(s).`:

```
IsSuccess = response == null ? false : true;
ResponseMessage = resp == true ? "Success" : "Failure",
```

I understand that [Null-Coalescing / Null-Coalescing-Assignment operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) can be used like:

```
variable ??= expression;
```

which is a shorthand for:

```
if (variable is null)
{
    variable = expression;
}
```

Can I make use of the same in my ternary expressions also?

Comment: IsSuccess = response != null;

seems to be the same or
 IsSuccess = !(response == null);

Comment: `response == null` is a boolean expression so the explicit values are redundant and perhaps more important you have them reversed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are getting this issue as you can rewrite

```
IsSuccess = response == null ? false : true;
```

As

```
IsSuccess = response != null;
```

For the second expression you can rewite

```
ResponseMessage = resp == true ? "Success" : "Failure";
```

As

```
ResponseMessage = resp ? "Success" : "Failure";
```

The ternary operator is just expecting a bool on the lefthand side of the '?' as such if the value is already a bool you have no need to test it.